# java upcasting polymorphism issue

Tags: java, polymorphism, upcasting

2 classes, A and B. class B inherits from class A.
What's wrong with the following code?

```
B b3 = (A)(new B());
```

Why isn't it a legal Upcasting?

It make sense. B instructor creates the B part of the whole object then A create its part and then it acts like A.

Comment: Shoot I had a detailed answer and this was closed when I was about to post it!

Comment: Just for the record: if you consider my answer helpful beyond the DUP question/answer ... feel free to accept it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

This is not legal because a B must be a B, not an A. That cast to A "invalidates" that assignment.